# Accessing request data object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am sending the following post Data to django Rest API

```html
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100
Content-Length: 90
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 11:01:54 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.5
Vary: Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83
content-type: text/plain
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.170 Mobile Safari/537.36


   
0:
{id: "1", username: "admin", password: "admin", user_group_id: "1", status: "1"}
```

The sent here will first be authenticated against the one saved in the database. I am trying to access this data but failing to do so . 
When I process the data using json parse

case 1.

```
def dunction(request)
data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
vak=data
return HttpResponse(vak)
```

Then the following response is received

```
{'id': '1', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin', 'user_group_id': '1', 'status': '1'}
```

case 2.
When manipulating the same code

```
data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
vak=data[0]
return HttpResponse(vak)
```

received response

```
idusernamepassworduser_group_idstatus
```

Case 3.

```
def dunction(request):
  data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
  vak=data.username
  return HttpResponse(vak)
```

> throws error `'list' object has no attribute 'username'`

FYI,
Here I am trying to create a custom authentication function which authenticates the userData and then sends data back to the server.

```
 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':  
    'polls.authentication.UserAuthentication',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpResponse takes an iterable. You are passing it various things that are in fact iterable: in the first case, a list, so it prints the (only) entry in that list, which is a dictionary; in the second case, you pass it a dict, so it iterates through the dict which gives the keys only. In the third case, for some reason you try and use object notation to access a key of a dict which is inside a list, which won't work at all.

I'm not sure what your actual question is, but if you do want to access the username you would need `data[0]['username']`.

Note though that the point of DRF is to abstract away a lot of this stuff; you should use the built-in functionality rather than doing any of this.

Answer (score 1):

Use request.data to get the data for processing. return message along with HTTP status code like below

```
def dunction(request):
  username=request.data['username']
  password=request.data['password']
  group_id=request.data['user_group_id']
  status=request.data['status']
  return Response({"status":"success"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```